# How can I plot a large array of Scatter3d subplots using plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, subplot, scatter3d

I want to create a large number of Scatter3d plots in a plotly subplots array.  When I plot 16 or fewer plots, everything renders correctly, but when I try to plot e.g. 25 plots in a 5x5 array, only the last 16 plots are rendered.

How can I get more than 16 plots to render correctly?

[image: 16 plots out of 25 render correctly]

Running the code below produces the problem demonstrated in the screenshot above.  However, if you edit line 7 to read `nrow,ncol = 4,4` then 16 plots render correctly.  This problem does not seem to occur with other plot types (e.g. Scatter).

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import numpy as np

Npts = 30
nrows,ncols = 5,5
speclist = [[{"type": "Scatter3d"} for i in range(0,ncols)] for j in range(0,nrows)]

fig = make_subplots(rows=nrows,cols=ncols,specs=speclist)

for i in range(0,nrows*ncols):
    row,col = (i//ncols)+1,(i%ncols)+1
    print("Index: {i:02d} Row: {row:02d} Column: {col:02d}".format(i=i,row=row,col=col))
    xvals=np.random.uniform(0.0,1.0,Npts)
    yvals=np.random.uniform(0.0,1.0,Npts)
    zvals=np.random.uniform(0.0,1.0,Npts)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=xvals, y=yvals, z=zvals,mode='markers',showlegend=False),row=row,col=col)

fig.show()
```

Comment: See the console warnings "_Too many active WebGL contexts. Oldest context will be lost_" and the subsequent errors. This is a browser limitation, on Chrome the number of WebGL contexts is limited to 16. There is an opened [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2333) about this.